# Inverter ordem de array

Tags: javascript

Tenho o array:

```
var meuArray = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 4];
```

Como inverter a ordem para que fique da seguinte maneira:

```
[4, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Como outras respostas já indicaram, você pode usar o método [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) da array. Mas atenção que isso altera a array original, e tem vezes em que é necessário ter uma cópia.

Para evitar a alteração do array original, você pode usar o [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) antes. Esse método é feito para gerar uma nova array que seja uma "fatia" da original. Mas se você passar `0` como primeiro argumento, essa fatia será um clone da array original completa:

```
var meuArray = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 4];
var meuArrayInvertido = meuArray.slice(0).reverse();
```

Comment: +1, tinha esquecido da possibilidade de usar o slice para clonar o array.

Comment: Acabei utilizando a sua solução. Só para entender melhor, com o `slice` funciona pois estou criando um novo array e faço a reversão nesse novo array, é isso né?

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior, o `slice` funciona como um `substring`, porém com `Array`, ao fazer um `slice(0, null)` ele está criando um segundo array com os elementos partindo do indice 0 até final do array, ou seja `slice(0)` irá clonar o array original.

Answer (score 7):

Pedro, apesar do [`Array.prototype.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) funcionar no seu exemplo, ele irá mutar o array original, então se fizer um `console.log(meuArray)` você irá notar que o mesmo estará invertido.

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output")
var log = function (object) {
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  container.textContent = JSON.stringify(object);
  output.appendChild(container);
}

var meuArray = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 4];
log(meuArray);

var meuArrayInvertido = meuArray.reverse();
log(meuArray);

log(meuArrayInvertido);
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Neste caso não faz muito sentido instanciar um objeto `meuArrayInvertido`, já que o array original foi invertido também. então neste caso você pode usar o [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para fazer o trabalho.

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output")
var log = function (object) {
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  container.textContent = JSON.stringify(object);
  output.appendChild(container);
}

var meuArray = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 4];
log(meuArray);

var meuArrayInvertido = meuArray.map(function (item, indice, array){
  return array[array.length - indice - 1];
});
log(meuArray);

log(meuArrayInvertido);
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, não tinha me ligado dessa questão. De qualquer forma acabei utilizando a solução do @bfavaretto

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior, a solução do bfavaretto está muito boa, eu tambem usuaria a dele ;D

Answer (score 5):

Pode usar um ciclo `for` e fazer troca de elementos dos elementos:

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
alert(array);
var length = array.length;
var left = null;
var right = null;
for (left = 0, right = length - 1; left < right; left += 1, right -= 1) {
  var temporary = array[left];
  array[left] = array[right];
  array[right] = temporary;
}
alert(array);
```

(Veja [aqui](http://jsperf.com/inverter-array) a comparação entre este método e o `.reverse()` em termos de performance).

Em termos de legibilidade e complexidade, se estiver a lidar com *arrays* pequenos e invertidos poucas vezes, o `.reverse()` e mais simples. No entanto, se for critica a performance da inversão, usa o método com o ciclo.

Answer (score 4):

Como o [TobyMosque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2363/tobymosque) respondeu, sobre a alteração no `array`, desenvolvi uma outra alternativa para a ocasião.

Defini uma função para o protótipo `Array`, está função pega o `this`, que nada mais é do que a variável do "tipo" `Array` que chama a função, e com um `for` decrescente, usando a função `push()` para cria um novo `array` com a ordem invertida retornando no fim da função.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Define uma função no prototipo do Array
// para retornar o mesmo com valores em orderm invertida.
Array.prototype.inverter = function() {
  var arr = [];
  for(i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     arr.push(this[i]);
  }
  return arr;
}

var nArr = arr.inverter();

// Saida de dados.
document.writeln(
  JSON.stringify(arr),
  JSON.stringify(nArr)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira que encontrei e utilizando o [reverse](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp)

```
var meuArray = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 4];
var meuArrayInvertido = meuArray.reverse();
//meuArrayInvertido === [4, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Tenha em atenção que o *array* original também e invertido desta forma.

Answer (score -3):

Como respondido nas respostas anteriores, o reverse irá inverter o array, mas você sabe o que acontece por trás dos panos?

Vou mostrar aqui, de forma matemática, como você pode inverter qualquer array:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
let temp;

console.log("Array original: " + array);

for (let i = 0; i < (array.length - 1) / 2; i++) {
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[(array.length - 1) - i];
    array[(array.length - 1) - i] = temp;
}

console.log("Array inverso: " + array);
```

Basicamente estou fazerdo um for que caminha de 0 à metade do tamanho do meu array.

No início estou criando um array com 10 posições (0 a 10) e crindo uma variável tempóraria, onde depois irei armazenar um valor nela.

Logo após faço toda a lógica para inverter o array:

- Crio um laço para caminha o array do primeiro elemento até a metade dele.
- Na váriavel temp armazeno os primeiros valores do meu array.
- Depois estou adicionando nos primeiros valores do meu array os ultimos valores.
- E por fim, estou adicionando no meus ultimos valores a variável temp, que está armazendo meus valores iniciais do array.

Comment: Código fonte do Google V8 implementando o método `Array.prototype.reverse()`: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/0b81f67b12550c118f1a94528c73e1cec01263a2/src/array.js#L560-L593

Comment: Código fonte dos navegadores Apple(Webkit) implementando o método `Array.prototype.reverse()` https://trac.webkit.org/browser/webkit/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArrayPrototype.cpp?rev=198294#L734 mais implementação da função `std::reverse` utilizado https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: Código fonte do Firefox implementando o método `Array.prototype.reverse()`: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/66a95a483d2c/js/src/jsarray.cpp#l1283

Comment: Especificação ECMA Script 262 do método `Array.prototype.reverse()`: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.reverse

Answer (score -4):

```js
function revert(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return []
  }
  return [array[array.length - 1]].concat(revert(array.slice(a, -1)))
}

console.log(revert([1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 4]))
```

Comment: Esse código não funciona e de onde surgiu esse `a` em `array.slice(a, -1)`? Em linguagens cujo a as chamadas de função são realizadas em stack frame onde não disponibilizam tail call, a profundidade de recursão é limitada ao tamanho do stack, significando que sua função caso a conserte funcionará em um array de poucos elementos mais usada em um array mais robusto irá levantar erro de call stack.